# Is it possible to rescue file descriptor from FILE*?

Tags: c, file, posix, fclose, fdopen

I have to use a certain cross-platform library which passes `FILE*` objects around.

I get a file descriptor from another source (inherited), I want to keep **same `fd`** across `fork`'d processes.

I currently use `fdopen` to convert a file descriptor to a `FILE*` object.

My problem is that `fclose` used to clean up `FILE*` objects closes connected file descriptor.

I would very much like to keep this file descriptor after it has been used.

is there a way rescue file descriptor from `FILE*`?

Is there a way to detach it?

Or a way to substitute a file descriptor in `FILE*` with a dummy?

P.S. this needs to be cross-platform, well across POSIX anyway.

Answer (score 2):

> My problem is that `fclose` used to clean up `FILE*` objects closes
>   connected file descriptor.

You could use [`dup(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html) to get a copy of the descriptor. Then the `close(2)` that `fclose(3)` does won't do anything.

> I need to maintain exact same fd number

Then call `dup2` again after `fclose`: `dup2(savedfd, rescuedfd)`

Comment: Please read again, I need to maintain exact same `fd` number due to `fork`'s

Comment: Hey, this might actually work. It's not thread-safe though, as another thread may allocate this very fd number between `close` and `dup2`. `dup3` will highlight this case but not solve it. I'll think about it!

Comment: @qarma There are other tricks to help you, like hijacking `fclose` etc. I wouldn't go that road though.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing that `fd` is your file descriptor and `f` your FILE* got from it. Maybe something like the following will do the trick:

```
fd2 = dup(fd);
fclose(f);
dup2(fd2, fd);
close(fd2);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you get a file descriptor from another source, Try to get its filename from that file descriptor. (Some says its possible using platform specific method. -google it.)

Once you get filename then fopen it again and get FILE* and do your work and clean up it using fclose.

Your original fd will not be disturbed.

Comment: +1 for the clever idea, I can do that on linux with `open("/proc/self/fd/9")`, but not OSX or any BSD clone.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-portable idea (vote if you think this is good/best):

GNU libc provides `fopencookie` and BSD provides equivalent `funopen`.

These return real `FILE*` handle, but implementation is your own:

It is then relatively trivial to map read/write/seek/close functions to underlying system calls:

```
read/readfn(cookie, buf, size){ return read((int)cookie, buf, size); }
write/writefn(cookie, buf, size) { return write((int)cookie, buf, size); }
seek/seekfn(cookie, offs, arg) { return seek((int)cookie, offs, arg); } // may require arg mapping to whence
close/closefn(cookie) {} // that's the whole point!
```